# I keep getting an error and I dont know why?

Tags: java, android

```
public class Help extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton floatButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder helpAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    helpAlert.setMessage("Send emails to - support@livescoresforyou.com - for more help!")
                            .setPositiveButton("Got It!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            })
                            .setTitle("Extra Help")
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp)
                            .create();
                    helpAlert.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I keep getting stuck and I cant get the floating action button to display what I want it too. Please help!

Comment: Try to post the log trace when you are facing error and show your XML file also

Comment: which error you are getting buddy?

Comment: The error is occurring on                 AlertDialog.Builder helpAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); its the (this) which has a red squiggly line under it.

Comment: But what error *is* it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are writing:

```
AlertDialog.Builder helpAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

inside an Anonymous Class. Inside an Anonymous Class, `this` is acting as the reference of your Anonymous Class (`new View.OnClickListener`) which is not extending the `Activity` (or `AppCompatActivity`) so the above line is giving you an error.

To remove the error simply change your above line to:

```
AlertDialog.Builder helpAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Help.this);
```

Here as I can see `Help` is your class name which is extending `AppCompatActivity` so this will not give any error.

Comment: Thanks dude spent about 2 hours trying to figure out what was wrong. Very grateful!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_help" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

is the XML file.
Is the XML file

Comment: hey callum, you can edit your question to include this instead of posting it as an answer to your own question :P Looks like you're doing a lot of things in one place. Remove the anchor stuff and use regular android:src in your FAB and see what happens. You might also want to alignParentBottom="true" on the FAB as well just so you know where it's going. It might be appearing behind something or just not at all. 
Also, a good way to sanity check your view in future is to programatically find it (findViewById(R.id.fab)) and then check that its height and width aren't 0.